# Loop breaking every time in slot machine program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to break the loop by saying

```
if deff <= int(total):
    break
```

but the loop will break regardless of the input being negative or more than the total it will break the loop

any advice of what am i doing wrong?

P.S i know i will new a formula to decide if player won or lost. right now im just trying to figure out the first code before going there

first time on programming and teacher not helpful ):

---

```
def intro():

    greeting()

    print('How much money do you want to start with?')

    print('Enter the starting amount of dollars.', end='')
    total = int(input())

    print('Your current total is '+ str(total)+'\n')
    while True:

        print('How much money do you want to bet (enter 0 to quit)?', end='');
    # Bett will be the amount of money that the player will play with

        bett = int(input())
        if bett > int(total):
            print('ERROR You don\'t have that much left')

        if bett < int(0):
            print('ERROR: Invalid bet amount\n')

        if bett <= int(total)
            break

# Function shows results of slot machine after handle being pulled
def random():
    import random

    num1 = random.randint(1, 5)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 5)
    num3 = random.randint(1, 5)

    print('/---+---+---\  ')
    print('|-'+ str (num1)+'-|-'+ str(num2) +'-|-'+ str (num3) +'-|')
    print('\---+---+---/  ')



intro()
```

---

Comment: The code works for me (after obvious corrections), what problem do you have exactly?

Comment: I would advise against naming your function `random` since you already have a module named `random`.  Technically it works but you should be careful.

Comment: Are you sure it breaks when `bett` is greater than `total`, as well as when it's negative?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `elif` and `else` in the successive conditional tests:

```
    bett = int(input())
    if bett > total:
        print('ERROR You don\'t have that much left')

    elif bett < 0:
        print('ERROR: Invalid bet amount\n')

    else:
        break
```

That way, only one of the statements in executed, instead of more or more.

NB:
It's not necessary to use the`int()` constructor all the time on something that is already an `int`

Comment: This is not strictly necessary and doesn't solve any problems unless I'm missing something.

Comment: No, this should do it. The first `elif` isn't _strictly_ necessary, since the first and second conditions can't both be true (assuming `total > 0`, but it's still clearer to include it.

Comment: @wRAR OP's problem. (Though it is missing a colon.)

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I don't have problems with OP's code (not counting the missing colon).

Comment: @wRAR OP does, though. The `while` loop was breaking when it shouldn't have (or rather, when he didn't intend it to).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard that's why I asked him to provide more info.

Comment: @Ber thank you!
it actually help now I can move on to the slot machine code (:
I would love to have every single one of you as my teacher, since mine doesn't want to take the time to show me my mistake or correct me

Answer (score 0):

In this block:

```
    if bett <= int(total)
        break
```

You have a syntax error.  Add a colon to the end of hte first line:

```
    if bett <= int(total):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would use a while loop.

```
play = True
while play == True:
    #all the code
    #to be executed
    #indented here
    #
    #Ask user if they want to continue playing
    p = input("Play again?[y/n] ")
    playAgain = str(p)

    if playAgain == "y":
        play = True
    else:
        play = False
```